# Selenium implicitly_wait error

Tags: selenium, pytest

Just got a problem using Selenium+Pytest. Created a test in office, it worked well. Then I wanted to modify it at home, intalled selenium, pytest, added geckodriver in PATH.

That's what I see when runnig a test:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-2.9.0, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: C:\Users\Jawdet\PycharmProjects\Autotests_UI, inifile: 
collected 1 items

test_add_house.py F
self = <test_add_house.test_add_house testMethod=test_add_house>

    def setUp(self):
        self.wd = WebDriver()
>       self.wd.implicitly_wait(30)

test_add_house.py:21: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:691: in implicitly_wait
    'implicit': int(float(time_to_wait) * 1000)})
env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:238: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x03CA8F30>
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Not a Number","stacktrace":"stack backtrace:\\n...      0x416877 - <no info>\\n   7:           0x66ed53 - <no info>\\n   8:     0x7fff1b6e8364 - BaseThreadInitThunk"}}'}

    def check_response(self, response):
        """
            Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an error.

            :Args:
             - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
               object.

            :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
            """
        status = response.get('status', None)
        if status is None or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
            return
        value = None
        message = response.get("message", "")
        screen = response.get("screen", "")
        stacktrace = None
        if isinstance(status, int):
            value_json = response.get('value', None)
            if value_json and isinstance(value_json, basestring):
                import json
                try:
                    value = json.loads(value_json)
                    if len(value.keys()) == 1:
                        value = value['value']
                    status = value.get('error', None)
                    if status is None:
                        status = value["status"]
                        message = value["value"]
                        if not isinstance(message, basestring):
                            value = message
                            try:
                                message = message['message']
                            except TypeError:
                                message = None
                    else:
                        message = value.get('message', None)
                except ValueError:
                    pass

        exception_class = ErrorInResponseException
        if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
            exception_class = NoSuchElementException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
            exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW:
            exception_class = NoSuchWindowException
        elif status in ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE:
            exception_class = StaleElementReferenceException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotVisibleException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE:
            exception_class = InvalidElementStateException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SELECTOR \
                or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR \
                or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR_RETURN_TYPER:
            exception_class = InvalidSelectorException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_IS_NOT_SELECTABLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotSelectableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COOKIE_DOMAIN:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_SET_COOKIE:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        elif status in ErrorCode.TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.SCRIPT_TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = UnexpectedAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = NoAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            exception_class = ImeNotAvailableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_ENGINE_ACTIVATION_FAILED:
            exception_class = ImeActivationFailedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.MOVE_TARGET_OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
            exception_class = MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
        else:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        if value == '' or value is None:
            value = response['value']
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
                raise exception_class(response, value)
            raise exception_class(value)
        if message == "" and 'message' in value:
            message = value['message']

        screen = None
        if 'screen' in value:
            screen = value['screen']

        stacktrace = None
        if 'stackTrace' in value and value['stackTrace']:
            stacktrace = []
            try:
                for frame in value['stackTrace']:
                    line = self._value_or_default(frame, 'lineNumber', '')
                    file = self._value_or_default(frame, 'fileName', '<anonymous>')
                    if line:
                        file = "%s:%s" % (file, line)
                    meth = self._value_or_default(frame, 'methodName', '<anonymous>')
                    if 'className' in frame:
                        meth = "%s.%s" % (frame['className'], meth)
                    msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                    msg = msg % (meth, file)
                    stacktrace.append(msg)
            except TypeError:
                pass
        if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
            raise exception_class(response, message)
        elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException and 'alert' in value:
            raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, value['alert'].get('text'))
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Not a Number

env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:193: WebDriverException
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
self.wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will wait for every web element for 60 seconds.